# Angular JS Validation - How to turn off required for a single field

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-validation

I'm trying to turn off the required attribute for a single input field in an Angular form on submit, if a certain condition is not met. I have tried the following:

```
form.ChangeCreditCard.$setValidity("required", false);
```

And even manually setting the $valid state for the field:

```
form.ChangeCreditCard.$valid = true;
```

But the field and thus the form is still invalid. Is there any way I could turn off validation on a single field in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ngRequired** https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRequired

> The directive sets the required attribute on the element if the
>   Angular expression inside ngRequired evaluates to true. A special
>   directive for setting required is necessary because we cannot use
>   interpolation inside required. See the interpolation guide for more
>   info.

Comment: Thanks, this was the way to go. Out of interest, is there a way to do it using $setValidity?

Comment: Yes. Here's a working jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gm97L3r5/
form.ChangeCreditCard.$setValidity("required", false); this should have been set to true :-)  It means it's valid.

Comment: oh so simple. Thanks